# Best compression technique for binary data?

Tags: compression

I have a large binary file that represents the alpha channel for each pixel in an image - 0 for transparent, 1 for anything else. This binary data needs to be dynamically loaded from a text file, and it would be useful to get the maximum possible compression in it. De-compression times aren't majorly important (unless we're talking a jump of say a minute to an hour), but the files need to be as small as possible.

Methods we've tried so far are using run length encoding, then a huffman coding, then converting the binary data to base64, and run length encoding but differentiating between zero and one using numeric values for one and alphabetical equivalents for zero (seems to give the best results). However, we're wondering if there's a better solution than either of these as we're approaching it from a logical standpoint, rather than looking at all possible methods.

Comment: Why can't you simply use an existing popular image format that has built-in compression, such as png, rather than invent your own?

Comment: Asaph +1. Also which compression technique is "best" depends very much on what kind of data do you have: imagine 1-bit images obtained by leveling a photo and a screenshot.

Comment: What @Asaph says. There are thoroughly optimized and researched image compression formats with man-decades or centuries of work in them for any kind of image (namely JPG for photos, and PNG). Don't re-invent the wheel

Comment: The system that will be decoding the data (World fo Warcraft) can't use conventional images - we could use the built in file format for the images, but there are no functions inbuilt in the system for processing the image, and we need to do collision detection on the image, so the binary grid is necessary.

Comment: If you can't use conventional formats, what about just trying to zip the data to see what savings you can get from that? I have to admit I've never developed anything for WoW so am unfamiliar with its limitations. A bit of binging brought up a project for VisualStudio that lets you make WoW addons (http://addonstudio.codeplex.com/), you may want to shoot them a message and ask if they know of any good ways to improve file compression for the game.

Comment: What do you mean by "World of Warcraft"? I find it hard to believe you're one of the programmers on Blizzard's team working on WoW. What exactly are you working on/with?

Comment: This question is months old now, but the World of Warcraft API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As external libraries were out fo the question, I created a custom solution for this. The system used run length encoding to compress the data, then the RLE encoded data was represented in base32 (32 characters for the zeroes, and the matching set for ones). This allowed us to represent files approximately 5MB in size with only around 30KB, without any loss.

Comment: Mind providing some code?

Comment: Base 32 makes sense here. You'd have long patterns of zeroes, so using base 32 means you can essentially store more information per digit. 

So if you had 512 zeroes, you could represent it as G00. 3 bytes instead of 512 bytes.

But you're working with a best-case here, so there's that.

Comment: @TastyLemons - You don't need code examples, he explained everything you need to build this.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, you should be best off by using an existing proven image format. If you must do it yourself you will probably still end up with something that is very close to some existing tech.

I would think that I would like to store how many times the following byte is repeated
|10|1|1|0|3|1|5|0

Would produce

1111111111011100000

But if one looks at this and optimize it on a byte level you would soon se that this is almost exactly what RLE -compresion does. So long answer made short, take a look at RLE ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Check out 7-Zip.  It has very good compression ratios, often a tenth the size of zip, and has language bindings for many programming languages.

http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html